# Symbolic polynomial factorization in Sympy/Python

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to see whether it is possible to get single variable polynomials,given as a string of coefficient/variable degree, into a factorized form. The coefficients of these polynomials are to be "symbols" and so have to be the factors in the output of the function.

So, if I gave as input a polynomial in the form

```
x**2-c**2
```

I would expect the function to give back:

```
(x+c)*(x-c)
```

However, in `sympy` I cannot make it work for anything more than trivial. If I first declare:

```
from sympy import *
x, a, b, c = symbols('x a b c')
```

Then something as simple as:

```
factor(x**2-a**2)
```

Works:

(−+)(+)

But already:

```
factor(x**2-a)
```

Fails:

−+2

Of course, even slightly more complicated polynomials like a full second order won't work.

```
factor(-x**2-a*x-3,x)
```

gives out:

−−2−3

Am I just misusing the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you as asking for is not really "factorisation" in the traditional sense. Usually factorisation means that you have a ring (e.g. integers, polynomials etc) and you have some element say `z` of the ring and you want to find two (or more) elements `x` and `y` so that `z = x*y`. For this to make sense you first need to define what your ring is.

In your example `x**2 - a**2` the natural choice of ring is the ring of polynomials in `x` and `a` with integer coefficients. This ring is typically denoted as `R = Z[x,a]`. Your polynomial `p1 = x**2 - a**2` is an element of `R` and so also are `p2 = x + a` and `p3 = x - a`. That means that within the ring `R` we can factorise `p1` into `p2*p3` where `p2` and `p3` are also elements of the ring `R`.

SymPy has algorithms to compute a factorisation in a given ring `R` but they need to work within the ring `R` (or else the problem is not well defined). When you ask to factorise `x**2 - a` I presume that you are hoping to get `(x - sqrt(a))*(x + sqrt(a))` but that is a factorisation into expressions that are *not* elements of the ring `R` (for the natural choice of `R`). This is like asking to factorise an integer but expecting the algorithm to find non-integer factors: e.g. `7 = (14/3)*(3/2)` would not usually be considered a "factorisation" of the prime number `7`.

SymPy's factor function has a number of arguments that can be used to affect what ring is used for factorisation e.g.:

```
In [12]: factor(x**2 - 2)
Out[12]: 
 2    
x  - 2

In [13]: factor(x**2 - 2, extension=sqrt(2))
Out[13]: (x - √2)⋅(x + √2)

In [14]: factor(x**2 + 2*sqrt(2)*x + 2)
Out[14]: 
 2             
x  + 2⋅√2⋅x + 2

In [15]: factor(x**2 + 2*sqrt(2)*x + 2, extension=True)
Out[15]: 
        2
(x + √2) 

In [16]: factor(x**2 + 1)
Out[16]: 
 2    
x  + 1

In [17]: factor(x**2 + 1, gaussian=True)
Out[17]: (x - ⅈ)⋅(x + ⅈ)
```

There is no option though to factorise in an extension that includes say `sqrt(a)` where `a` is a symbol.

Most likely "factorisation" in its usual sense is not really what you are interested in and is probably not the best word to use which is why SymPy's `factor` function does not do what you were expecting it to do. It sounds to me like what you want to do is express a polynomial in terms of its roots rather than its coefficients. Unlike factorisation rather than specifying a ring this requires specifying that some variable of your polynomial is the "main variable" whose roots you are interested in. I will presume that `x` is intended to be the main variable:

```
In [19]: from sympy import *

In [20]: x, a = symbols('x, a')

In [21]: p = 2*x**2 - 2*a

In [22]: LC(p, x) * prod((x - r) for r in roots(p, x, multiple=True))
Out[22]: 2⋅(-√a + x)⋅(√a + x)

In [23]: p2 = -x**2-a*x-3

In [24]: LC(p2, x) * prod((x - r) for r in roots(p2, x, multiple=True))
Out[24]: 
 ⎛           _________⎞ ⎛           _________⎞
 ⎜          ╱  2      ⎟ ⎜          ╱  2      ⎟
 ⎜a       ╲╱  a  - 12 ⎟ ⎜a       ╲╱  a  - 12 ⎟
-⎜─ + x - ────────────⎟⋅⎜─ + x + ────────────⎟
 ⎝2            2      ⎠ ⎝2            2      ⎠
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are working only with low order polynomials you can use `Mul(*[x - i for i in solve(eq, x)])` to rebuild the expression from solutions for `x`.

```py
from sympy.abc import a, x
from sympy import Mul, solve
eq = -a*x - x**2 - 3
>>> Mul(*[x - i for i in solve(eq, x)])
(a/2 + x - sqrt(a**2 - 12)/2)*(a/2 + x + sqrt(a**2 - 12)/2)
```